# split byte array per value of one byte

Tags: c#

I have a byte array and I want to split per value of 1 byte. like string.split.

for example: if my byte array has this data: `0x00,0x0A,0x02,0x0A,0X03,0x0A`

```
b_arr0[0] = 0x00;
b_arr0[1] = 0x0a;
b_arr1[0] = 0x02;
b_arr1[1] = 0x0a;
b_arr2[0] = 0x03;
b_arr2[1] = 0x0a;
```

Comment: No. I want at the end 3 byte arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the byte array using a certain byte as separator in a similar way as `String.Split`, you can do it like this:

```
public byte[][] Split(byte[] input, byte separator, bool ignoreEmptyEntries = false)
{
    var subArrays = new List<byte[]>();
    var start = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= input.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (input.Length == i || input[i] == separator)
        {
            if (i - start > 0 || ignoreEmptyEntries)
            {
                var destination = new byte[i - start];
                Array.Copy(input, start, destination, 0, i - start);
                subArrays.Add(destination);
            }
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }

    return subArrays.ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

```
var bytes = new byte[]
{
    0x00,
    0x01,
    0xaa, // Split here.
    0x02,
    0x03,
    0xaa, // Split here.
    0x04,
    0x05
};
var splitted = Split(bytes, separator: 0xaa, ignoreEmptyEntries: true);
```

Note that the separator byte is not included in the output arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with this LINQ query?

```
byte[][] b_arr1 = data
    .Select((b, ix) => new { Byte = b, Index = ix })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2, x => x.Byte)
    .Select(byteGroup => byteGroup.ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```